# Need connection between TWO tables PHP/MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, insert

This is my code:

```
    <?php
    $target_dir = "videoCover/";
    $target_dir = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk=1;

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_dir . $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"])) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($uploadFile_size > 128000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }


    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk==0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else { 
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }



    include '../connect/con.php';

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
    $vidTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTitle']);
    $imgCover = $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['uploadFile']['size'];
    $type = $_FILES['uploadFile']['type'];
    $url = '/upload/videoCover/'.$_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"];
    $vidSD = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidSD']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO newsvid (id, vidTitle, imgCover, size, type, url, vidSD) VALUES ('$id', '$vidTitle', '$imgCover', '$size', '$type', '$url', '$vidSD')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }echo "Video links are added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>


    <?php

    include '../connect/con.php';


    if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){

        $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
        $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
        $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
        $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
        $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++){
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "videoScreenShots/".$name_array[$i])){
                echo $name_array[$i]." upload is complete<br>";
                $imgShot[$i]='videoScreenShots/'.$name_array[$i];
            } else {
                echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for ".$name_array[$i]."<br>";
            }   
        }
}



    $idvi = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $vidLD = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidLD']);
    $vidYear = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidYear']);
    $vidCity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidCity']);
    $vidZanr = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidZanr']);
    $vidZanr2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidZanr2']);
    $vidZanr3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidZanr3']);
    $vidQuality = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidQuality']);
    $vidTranslated = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTranslated']);
    $vidTime = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidTime']);
    $vidMaker = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidMaker']);
    $vidRoles = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['vidRoles']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO videoinformation (id, vidLD, vidYear, vidCity, vidZanr, vidZanr2, vidZanr3, vidQuality, vidTranslated, vidTime, vidMaker, vidRoles, imgShot1, imgShot2, imgShot3) VALUES ('$idvi', '$vidLD', '$vidYear', '$vidCity', '$vidZanr', '$vidZanr2', '$vidZanr3', '$vidQuality', '$vidTranslated', '$vidTime', '$vidMaker', '$vidRoles', '".$imgShot[0]."','".$imgShot[1]."','".$imgShot[2]."')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }echo "Video Description are added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Question is i'm using this `$idvi = mysql_insert_id($con);` to get ID from first uploading information to first table (newsvid).

All what I need is: I have form which have a lot of different information  and I try to upload all this information into two different tables. In the way like uploading first to table1 and using id from table1 upload information to table2. Finally I'm stuck and do not get how I can do it (

**P.S.** Currently using this code I have just empty/blank page.

**P.P.S** Have an error: `Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (denzw681_u.videoinformation, CONSTRAINT videoinformation_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES newsvid (id))`

Comment: Why are you using mysql_insert_id() when you're using mysqli() everywhere?

Comment: And you are missing a closing `}` somewhere at the end, that's the cause of your current blank page.

Comment: Because I have no idea how to do another way... I need first add information to table (newsvid) and then using id from newsvid add information to tables (videoinformation)

Comment: Yes but why mysql()? Use mysqli_insert_id() instead?

Comment: ups))) my fault)) Anyway same problem.... as well if I missing "}"?? Where??? still blank page

Comment: if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){ <-- missing the closing bracket

Comment: Anyway, this code can use quite some improvement. Unfortunetely I'm always fighting with mysqli() so I prefer to use PDO() instead. Otherwise I'd have upgraded it for you and solved your problem aswell.

Comment: Any decent editor would make typographic errors fairly obvious. [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) is Eclipse-based and free.

Comment: @TiesonT. Or at least he could enable error reporting. That would've given him some clue instead of a blank page :P

Comment: Have error: Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`denzw681_u`.`videoinformation`, CONSTRAINT `videoinformation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `newsvid` (`id`))

Comment: I have newsvid (primary key ID) and have videoinformation with (foreign key id) from newsvid

Comment: In simple words it probebly means you're trying add something to a new table while the old one is still selected. Considder selecting everything from table1(parent) and from table2(child). Both have column "id". Now adding something to "id" in table2 is illegal because "id" in table1 is still selected. AKA "CONSTRAINT"

Comment: So what to do? need to close connectyion after first information added to table1 and the open again to add information to table2? Or i'm stuck......

Comment: I guess so. As I said. Not used to mysqli(). Never had the problem myself either. Just know what it means in general.

Comment: Solved.....get it now))

Comment: Glad you got it working :) If I may do a suggestion: Take a look at prepared statements :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need delete this bit:

```
mysqli_close($con);
?>


<?php

include '../connect/con.php';
```

Separation between adding things. Now it's working.

As well like others told mistake was instead of **mysqli** I used **mysql**

And was missing "}" now code is working ))